# ssh port forward when connected with ssh in script

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

when I am connected to a device over SSH, I know how to forward local ports;    first enter ssh menu with `[ENTER} ~C`, then:
`-L 4455:ip:80`

This will make localhost:4455 on my local machine go to port 80 on the remote device.

How can I instead put this manual action into a script? The only variable here is the IP address on the remote device, but I know how to get that automatically; I just don't know how to push commands to the ssh menu, such as: `-L 4455:ip:80`.

Comment: Why even use the menu? You can pass all of this directly on the command line.

Comment: @Panki sorry for the weird question, but how? i still have lots to learn about linux, but i'e always used the ssh menu to forward ports when connected over ssh, 

the code 'ssh -L 4455:ip:80' does not work
nor does 'ssh -N -L 4455:ip:80'

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

I recently ran into this post: https://hackertarget.com/ssh-examples-tunnels/ It explains a lot about ssh connections and port forwarding, have a look, you will learn a lot :)

Here is the bit that is relevant to you:

---

**SSH Tunnel (port forward)**

In its simplest form an SSH tunnel simply opens a port on your local system that connects through to another port at the other end of the tunnel.

`localhost:~$ ssh  -L 9999:127.0.0.1:80 user@remoteserver`

Lets break down the -L parameter. Think of -L as the Local listening side. So in our example above the port 9999 is listening on localhost and port forwards through to port 80 on remoteserver, note that the 127.0.0.1 refers to localhost on the remote server!

Lets take it up a notch. In this following example the port that is listening can be connected to from other hosts on the local network.

`localhost:~$ ssh  -L 0.0.0.0:9999:127.0.0.1:80 user@remoteserver`

In these examples the port we are connecting is a listening web server. It could also be a proxy server or any other TCP service.

---

### Examples

Now, the above will open an active SSH shell for you, and, as we only want to forward the port this is unwanted. You can add the -N argument to the command to skip executing any remote commands (the opened shell is a command too). The `ssh man` page explains this as well:

`-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.`

So, the following script will open your port until you ctrl-c/kill it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "Forwarding ports"
ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:9999:127.0.0.1:80 user@remoteserver
```

You can also open a port for a few seconds by executing a sleep command and removing the -N argument:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9999:127.0.0.1:80 user@remoteserver "sleep 10"
```

### Final

These SSH tunnels have their pitfalls. If you want to keep the forwarded port open for a long time, you might want to check out the following thread, specifically the bit about `autossh`: https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar to what you asked, which was to have a script that will automatically port forward using ssh and open a browser at that address.  To achieve this, I combined the automated behavior of ssh command with a shell script.  I'm using MacOS as an illustration.

In my ~/.ssh/config file, I have an entry, something like:

```
Host remoteserver
     HostName [ip address here]
     User [username]
     IdentityFile [path to secret.pem]
```

So if you type in `ssh remoteserver` you know it will connect you there.  Then I setup a separate script called `monitor` with `chmod +x` on and in a directory already in PATH, the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -L 9999:localhost:80 $1 -N &
open -na Google\ Chrome --args --new-window "http://localhost:9999"
```

So when you type `monitor remoteserver` it will automatically use ssh to establish the port forwarding and then open the Google Chrome browser at the appropriate address.

Just to explain, `$1` stands for the parameter that comes after the script file name.  `-N` stands for not requiring a terminal shell at the remote server.  `&` stands for non-blocking execution; if you did not have that, the next command of opening the browser window will wait until you are done with SSH, which is not what you want.  `Open` is what you'd typically use in Darwin of MacOS, and for an appropriate flavor of linux, you'd have to look it up, but it shouldn't be too hard.  `-na` stands for combining new process and application flags, and `--args --new-window` although seems redundant to the -n flag earlier, seems to work best with Chrome in my experience.

Hope this helps.